# Android Studio - removing table row programmatically

Tags: android, tablerow

I have created a table dynamically from an array list

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        TextView name = new TextView(this);
        TextView time = new TextView(this);
        TableRow row  = new TableRow(this);

        // Set event name and remaining time
        name.setText(arrayList.get(i).name);
        time.setText("...");

        // Add text views to row
        row.addView(time, layoutParams);
        row.addView(name, layoutParams);

        // Add row to table
        tableLayout.addView(row, i);
    }
```

Now if I want to edit or remove certain rows under a condition, I will have to access that row, but how?

```
    outerloop:
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++ ) {
        if(// row's time <= 0 ...) {
            tableLayout.removeViewAt(i); // this doesn't seem to work properly
                                         // it removes the wrong rows
        }
        else {
            // ...
            break outerloop;
        }
    }
```

For some reason `tableLayout.removeViewAt(i);` removes the incorrect row. Alternatively, I'd prefer to edit that row's `name`, but the principle applies, I just need to find a way to access the table row. Any way?

Comment: you can alternatively store your `row` in a list, and access them through that list.

Comment: when you remove first row from the tableLayout second row will become first row(index will change).

Comment: @JineshFrancis Ohhh I see!! Wasn't aware of that! Do you have any work-around?

Comment: @VladMatvienko I will try your suggestion too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your table like this:

```
ArrayList<TableRow> rows = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    TextView name = new TextView(this);
    TextView time = new TextView(this);
    TableRow row  = new TableRow(this);
    rows.add(row);

    // Set event name and remaining time
    name.setText(arrayList.get(i).name);
    time.setText("...");

    // Add text views to row
    row.addView(time, layoutParams);
    row.addView(name, layoutParams);

    // Add row to table
    tableLayout.addView(row, i);
}
```

When you want to remove a row now you can do that by it's index in the ArrayList:

```
row = rows.get(i);
table.removeView(row);
rows.remove(i);
```

When you want to remove multiple rows this could be a solution for you:

```
ArrayList<TableRow> removeRows = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
    if(....) {
        removeRows.add(rows.get(i));
    }
}

// now delete those rows
for(TableRow remove : removeRows) {
    tableLayout.removeView(row);
    rows.remove(remove);
}
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: It's awesome! Worked out just as wanted!

Comment: Also, `rows.remove(i);` is probably not needed? As it also messes up the removal of rows too, it seems.

Comment: It is not needed if you do not add any rows at a later time. Do you?

Comment: @AppPhil No, I first add the rows, then delete the row (if condition met), and those operations are done only once, so I guess not needed! Thank you!